# SSRS Chart - Length of Axis Label

Tags: reporting-services, axis-labels, reportbuilder3.0

Is there a way to specify the length of the string for each label on the X-axis?

I have very long string category values that are rotated 90 deg (reading vertical) and the chart auto-sizing is making the chart area very small in comparison to the axis label area.

I've tried Enabling the auto-fit and setting the wrapped option like in this post:
[How to Fix the X Axis values length in Microsoft chart controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737162/how-to-fix-the-x-axis-values-length-in-microsoft-chart-controls)

But it ends up with the same result as I have with Disabling auto-fit.

Is there some way to use the LabelsFormat option for a text string rather than a number/datetime?

Comment: From what I understand, `LabelFormat` can only be used to format numbers and dates. Are you looking to limit the number of characters displayed in the label string? Something like `Cat` instead of `Category`?

Comment: Yeah I want to limit the number of characters displayed in the labels so that the sizing of the chart area will increase.  In Word you can just adjust the chart area size with mouse control and it formats the labels.  Not sure what your referring to with Cat?  The x-axis labels are referred to as Category Groups.

Comment: `Cat` was just an example -- so if a sample category group value is `Category`, you want to truncate the string so the label reads `Cat`.

Comment: Oh ha, yeah that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't found a way to format character strings using the `LabelFormat` property.

One option is to use an expression in the `Label` property of the category group to limit the number of characters displayed. The below example limits the label string to 5 characters:

## Expression

```
=LEFT(Fields!CategoryGroupField.Value, 5)
```

## Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Ah yep that did it! Thanks, I tried earlier using LEFT() in the LabelFormat with no luck, just needed it in the Label property.

Comment: Here's the expression to add in the "Blah..." if length is over the trim value.

=Left(Fields!Package.Value, 25) & IIf(Len(Fields!Package.Value) > 25, "...", "")